# Make sure you have CONFIG access to the target Master

Tags: condor

While trying to setup a condor pool using two machines with CentOS-7 following [this tutorial in the official documentation](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-manual/quick-start-condor-pool.html)

when I type in the command

```
$ condor_store_cred add -c
```

I am prompted to enter a password. When I enter a password for the same I get the following error

```
Operation failed.
    Make sure you have CONFIG access to the target Master.
```

Can anyone explain why am I getting this error and how can I fix this so that I can get my condor pool up and running.

Comment: The tutorial was recently updated to address some issues; could you retry and see if you get the same error?

Comment: @JoshKarpel I am following the latest tutorial with HTCondor 8.8.12-1.el7.x86_64 (on RHEL-7.3) and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting the same error

Comment: No update yet. I haven't found the answer to the above question.

Comment: even if it is a very late reply but I assume it is due to the missing CONFIG_ALLOW variable in your condor_config. You need to specify that conf :

ALLOW_CONFIG = <the_user_you_created_to_manage>@<your file system domain>
or 
ALLOW_CONFIG = <your_network>